# Cannot get the group by query to take date into account

Tags: sql, mysql, join, count, group

**Table 1**

| URI | Date | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-03-05 | Fred |
| 2 | 2020-03-04 | Bob |
| 3 | 2020-03-03 | Fred |
| 4 | 2020-03-02 | Dave |
| 5 | 2020-03-01 | Dave |
| 6 | 2020-02-28 | Fred |
| 7 | 2020-02-27 | Bob |
| 8 | 2020-02-26 | Bob |
| 9 | 2020-02-25 | Fred |
| 10 | 2020-02-24 | Fred |

**Table 2**

| URI | Date | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-03-05 | Fred |
| 2 | 2020-03-04 | Bob |
| 4 | 2020-03-02 | Dave |
| 5 | 2020-03-01 | Dave |
| 6 | 2020-02-28 | Fred |
| 8 | 2020-02-26 | Bob |
| 9 | 2020-02-25 | Fred |
| 10 | 2020-02-24 | Fred |

I am trying to count the number of times the name is counted in the second table, when the date is the below the date on the line of the first table. So the output should be:

| URI | Count | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Fred |
| 2 | 1 | Bob |
| 3 | 3 | Fred |
| 4 | 1 | Dave |
| 5 | 0 | Dave |
| 6 | 2 | Fred |
| 7 | 1 | Bob |
| 8 | 0 | Bob |
| 9 | 1 | Fred |
| 10 | 0 | Fred |

I have managed to get to code to group and count the times each name appears in the second table, but I can't get it to count only those where the date is below the line date in the first table. I was hoping there was a relatively simple solution for this but cannot seem to get anything to work:

```
SELECT t1.uri,
       t1.date,
       t1.name,
       t2.cou
FROM       table1 t1
INNER JOIN (select name, 
                   count(name) AS cou
            FROM table2 t2
            GROUP BY name) t2 
        ON t1.name = t2.name
ORDER BY t1.uri
```

Comment: what's the dbms you're working with?

Comment: MySQL using HeidiSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
with all_data as (
    SELECT t1.URI, t1.TX_DATE, t1.FIRST_NAME
    ,t2.FIRST_NAME as count_name
    FROM TABLE1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 t2 on t1.first_name = t2.first_name and t1.tx_date > t2.tx_date
)
SELECT URI, TX_DATE, FIRST_NAME, count(count_name)
from all_data
group by URI, TX_DATE, FIRST_NAME
order by URI, TX_DATE, FIRST_NAME
;
```